# I need an Intent to pick a video with a specific format

Tags: android, android-intent, android-internal-storage, android-intent-chooser

I need to pick photo or video from the gallery.

But need to restrict video format for example only for `mp4` and `mov` or other specific later.

Can I achieve it with adding some options to this kind of code?

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
            startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `video/*` you should narrow it down to `video/mp4` or `video/quicktime` or both. Putting `*` basically means `all video formats`.

An example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
i.setType("*/*");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png", "video/mp4", "video/quicktime"});
startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

Comment: Can I pick both mov and mp4 format? Because seems mov is not supported by android?

Comment: Yes, by default Android is not supported playing .mov formatted video but you can work around this by using a 3rd party player like https://github.com/Tubitv/TubiPlayer or https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer. For picking .mov formatted video, I'm not sure if it'll work. Maybe you can try it and let us know from here :)

Comment: I can play it. The question is to pick it, and seems with this parameters mov is not pickable in android

Comment: https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker I think you can give this a try. As far as I understand, this library uses regex to pick custom extensions. (You can write your own regex for .mov extension)

Comment: Actually yes, quicktime is the same as mov. But android handles only quicktime keyword!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!